# Testing multiple public methods that call the same private method

Tags: api, unit-testing, testing, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I'm trying to figure out whether it's an API design flaw, it is actually OK, or the SRP is being violated.

I have 2 public methods `initialize()` and `onListRefresh()`. Both of them call the same private method `updateList()`. The only difference between both of them is that `initialize()` also check for a null argument to throw an exception.

The issue is that in order to test both public methods, I practically have to copy and paste the same mocks, stub, expectations and assertions, which are all for what happens on the private method, and it feels wrong. So which one is it:

1. Is there a flaw in the public API design?
2. It's all right, that's how it's supposed to be.
3. SRP is being violated by using `initialize()` to do both checking for an argument AND calling `updateList()`

Comment: Why doesn't `updateList` test the value as well?

Comment: It will be better to have some code... Anyway, what is the intentions of your methods ? Initialize, you had no value and you will have some value ? And refresh you have a value and you update it ? For me you should resonate with intention rather than method (often an intention will be exposed by a public method somehow)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with 2, and stick with the parallel tests. But here's something that may be calling to you from the test code: **Extract helper methods.**

This can happen anywhere in the Arrange, Act, Assert phases of the tests. You may extract helpers in all 3 phases. The trick is good names, so that the tests express, simply and legibly, what they are there for.